# How to change schema in Spring JPA based on request

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I have a multitenant system currently working with python. I have different schemas for different tenants. Now we are planning to change the system to spring boot.

How can we change/select the schema based on the request in JPA/Hibernate?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following property dynamically -
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=MYSCHEMA`. For more advanced concept of using multiple `datasources` take a look at [AbstractRoutingDatasource](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source)